# Use Perl to add a directory and its files and subdirectories to a zip archive

Tags: perl

This is the folder structure

```
9781471839108_epub
    - 9781471839108_epub_ncx_r1.ncx
    - 9781471839108_epub_opf_r1.opf
    - mimetype
    meta-inf
        - container.xml
    oebps
        - ack.htm
        - ch01.htm
        audio
            - 1.mp3
        images
            - 1-1.jpg
```

---

When I want to put file in second level folder ( `meta-inf` and `oebps`) all files are put in the main folder

How can I put files in their respective folders like 
in `meta-inf` folder I want to put `container.xml` file

---

Below is the coding which is done by me

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Cwd;
my $dir = getcwd;

use Archive::Zip;
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES );
use File::Basename 'basename';

my $zip         = Archive::Zip->new();
my $isbn_folder = "0";

opendir( min_dir, $dir ) or die "Cannot open $dir: $!";

foreach my $min_file ( readdir min_dir ) {
    if ( -d $min_file ) {
        $isbn_folder = $min_file;
    }
}
closedir min_dir;

my $isbn_folder_path = "$dir/$isbn_folder";
opendir( isbn_dir, $isbn_folder_path ) or die "Cannot open $dir: $!";
my @isbn_files = readdir( isbn_dir );
closedir isbn_dir;

foreach my $isbn_file ( @isbn_files ) {

    if ( -f "$isbn_folder_path/$isbn_file" ) {

        my @member = $isbn_file;

        foreach my $member ( @member ) {
            my $mine_file_path_add = "$isbn_folder_path/$member";
            my $member             = basename $mine_file_path_add;
            $zip->addFile( $mine_file_path_add, $member )
                or die 'unable to add file to archive';
        }
    }

    if ( -d "$isbn_folder_path/$isbn_file" ) {

        my @isbn_folder = $isbn_file;

        foreach my $isbn_folder ( @isbn_folder ) {

            if ( $isbn_folder =~ m/([0-9a-zA-Z])/ ) {

                my @isbn_folder1 = $isbn_folder;

                foreach my $isbn_folder1 ( @isbn_folder1 ) {

                    my $mine_file_path_add = "$isbn_folder_path/$isbn_folder1";
                    my $member             = basename $mine_file_path_add;

                    $zip->addDirectory( '$mine_file_path_add/', $member )
                        or die 'unable to add file to archive';

#__________I have problem to put this file on there respective dir______________

                    opendir( oebps_dir, $mine_file_path_add )
                        or die "Cannot open $dir: $!";
                    my @isbn_folder = readdir( oebps_dir );
                    closedir oebps_dir;

                    foreach my $isbn_folder ( @isbn_folder ) {

                        if ( -f "$mine_file_path_add/$isbn_folder" ) {

                            my @member = $isbn_folder;

                            foreach my $member ( @member ) {
                                my $mine_file_path_add =
                                    "$mine_file_path_add/$member";
                                my $member = basename $mine_file_path_add;
                                $zip->addFile( $mine_file_path_add, $member )
                                    or die 'unable to add file to archive';
                            }
                        }
                    }

#____________________________________
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

unless ( $zip->writeToFileNamed( "d:/perl/Tool/Test/making_epub/temp.zip" ) ==
    AZ_OK ) {
    die "whoops!";
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: i can't add 2 level file in there respective folder

Comment: in second level it have 2 folder:- (1) meta-inf and (2)oebps and in both it have some file but when i add file them, than all file are added in main dir which is 9781471839108_epub. i don't know why? :(

Comment: is any one can solve my problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you're specifically using `basename` to trim the path information from each file or directory that you store. If you had left the full path intact it would have reflected the disk directory structure in the zip archive

There is also no need to walk the file paths yourself, as the `Archive::Zip` methods `addTree` and `addTreeMatching` will do that for you

You haven't explained what you're trying to do, but from your Perl code it looks like you just want to store a whole directory structure in a zip file. There is one test in there

```
if ( $isbn_folder =~ m/([0-9a-zA-Z])/ )
```

which I think is there just to remove the `.` and `..` pseudo-directories

The directory that you select for storage is the *last* subdirectory of the current directory, which you can find with

```
my $base_folder = ( grep -d, glob '*')[-1];
```

and you can save that to the zip archive with a call to `addTree`, as shown below

I have used a `select` parameter that you can use to choose which files and directories are added to the archive. In this case it always returns *true*, so everything is archived, but it serves as a useful log of what files are being stored

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Archive::Zip qw/ :ERROR_CODES :MISC_CONSTANTS /;

use constant ZIP_FILE => 'D:\perl\Tool\Test\making_epub\temp.zip';

STDOUT->autoflush;

my $base_folder = ( grep -d, glob '*')[-1];

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new;

$zip->addTree({
  root => $base_folder,
  select => sub {
    say "Storing $_";
    1;
  },
  compressionLevel = DEFLATING_COMPRESSION_NORMAL,
});

$zip->writeToFileNamed(ZIP_FILE) == AZ_OK or die "Failed to save zip file: $!";

say "\nZip file written";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reply and today i am also try with addTree() and its working. But you are great for me bcz i am very new with perl

Comment: how can i contact you because i am sure again i need your help so please give me any contact reference like fb, what'up, BBM, etc..